# Having trouble with Safari while testing web site security

Tags: safari, security, google-chrome

I am building a web application which requires a *Basic Authentication* to access any URL. Let's say for example I am having a mapping like so, `/test`. On hitting this url ideally I should first get prompt for entering username and password and on entering correct user name and password I should be redirected to `/test`. But on doing this on safari it acts weird. It prompts me for username and password but even on entering the correct username and password it is not redirecting me to the `/test` url, and shows the login screen again. The same process works seamlessly on ***Chrome***. I have also tried clearing the cache and cookies but it is also not helping. I am using Springboot to create this application. Does anybody has any idea how to resolve this.

Comment: Please add a sample code - without it we can't know what the problem is